# What type of panels are on my shed?

Tags: repair, walls

Always worried about running into asbestos due to an older house. The guy built a lean to on the side of the shed. Is this asbestos panels or is it fiberglass?  [image]

[image]

Comment: corrugated fiberglass panels, also made from other materials. Check with Home Depot or Lowes. or a lumber supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my part of the planet, corrugated asbestos looks like this

[image]

It is a light-grey, opaque, harder and much less flexible than corrugated fibreglass (glass reinforced plastic).

What you have looks to me much more like corrugated fibreglass panels.